# ngFor loop through Object

Tags: loops, angular, ngfor

I trying to iterate through an object. I tried the following:

pipe:

```
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    if (!value) {
      return value;
    } 

let keys = [];
for (let key in value) {
  keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
} 
return keys;
```

} 
}

in my html:

```
<div *ngIf="details">
<li *ngFor=" let entry of details| keys">           
{{entry.key}},  {{entry.value}}
</li>
```

And its working, but it shows my whole object.
I just need certain keys of the object.
So I can do something like this ( this was an object with an array in it, this way is not working if its only an object):

```
<button ion-item *ngFor="let movie of movies?.results" (click)="goToDetails(movie.id)">
  <h2>{{movie.title}}</h2>
{{movie.overview}}
</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't `{{entry.value.yourDesiredKey}}` work? I don't understand the question

Comment: if you need certain keys.. doesn't *ngIf="entry.key==condition" within the loop work?

Comment: That won't work: I get an error  Cannot read property 'title' of null. The problem is that the ngFor is looping through my whole object. I just need to show certain parts. Like with ngFor you could loop through certain parts of it by doing something like {{entry.title}}

Comment: It should return the whole object as you are not filtering data at all in the pipe logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement either filter pipe or pass arguments (desired property names) to your pipe:

```
<li *ngFor=" let entry of details| keys:'name', 'value'">
//or
<li *ngFor=" let entry of details| keys | filter">
```

---

```
for (let key in value) {
  if(!Array.isArray(args) || args.length === 0 || args.indexOf(key) > -1)
  keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
} 

<li *ngFor=" let entry of details| keys:'name'">           
{{entry.key}},  {{entry.value}}
</li>
```

Comment: I tried to use your first line and used every single combination I could think of, but nothing shows up. If I want to show the title only, how could I do this?What should come between the {{}}. I'm new to this and I can't figure it out

Comment: added example using `args`

Comment: It doesnt not work. It will show the whole object. Angular is wrong for taking out the ngfor that loops through objects.

Comment: angular is actually correct, your `transform` signature is not correct, should be `public transform(value:any, ...args:any[]):any`

Comment: I'm just saying that the reason for taking it out wasn't legit. Thats why they're are working on a pipe for doing this. I'm trying out your suggestion now. thnx